# Can Paillier Encryption has independent decryption key?

Tags: encryption, public-key, paillier

As Pailliear cryptosystem secret key $\lambda$, depends on primes $p$ and $q$. As $\lambda = \operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$.

I want decryption key to independent from $p$ and $q$.

- It can be possible to generate decryption key independently?

Comment: Could you tell the reason? Maybe you are asking x but want y.

Comment: Can it be possible to generate a decryption key without knowledge of $p, q$ (e.g. with only knowledge of $n = pq$) - we most certainly hope not, as that would imply that Paillier is insecure.

Comment: @kelalaka My requirement is https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/73023/can-paillier-rsa-or-any-other-schemes-be-used-for-universal-re-encryption-like