# Deterministic procedure for mapping an arbitrary value into a , pair for public key cryptography

Tags: public-key, prime-numbers, paillier

I want public key cryptosystem to used for re-encryption as describe in [Can Paillier ,RSA or any other schemes be used for universal re-encryption like elGamal?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/73023/can-paillier-rsa-or-any-other-schemes-be-used-for-universal-re-encryption-like/73024?noredirect=1#comment161914_73024) 
Now i have little solution for Paillier cryptosystem, to choose key that is dependent on environmental variable. i,e `IP-Address` . 
The problem is how to map this environmental variable to generate two prime p and q, so that it can be regenerated in same way in decryption algorithm( Need decryption key to dependent on environmental variables).

**Is there way to map arbitrary variable(environmental key) to map/ generate p and q?**

Answer (score 0):

If you can have a secret key and it's fine for the party holding this key to also know the factorization, then yes this is quite easy.

Use your key to apply a pseudorandom function to the data you want the key determined by. If necessary use a pseudorandom generator to stretch the output.

Then use that output as the random coins for any standard probabilistic algorithm for generating two prime numbers with the required properties.